# Advice on the best way to group/link questions with a common theme

Tags: discussion

In answering a question about burnt resistors [Apparently open circuit resistor with 5 bands and white final band](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683074/apparently-open-circuit-resistor-with-5-bands-and-white-final-band/683104#683104) I've spotted that we've got quite a lot of similar questions (such as this one [Can anyone confirm this resistor value?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486655/can-anyone-confirm-this-resistor-value/683105#683105) ) where the answer is that the failed resistor is most likely a fusible resistor (combining current limiting and fusing).

I've tried to provide a clear, definitive answer to the most recent question, and edited the title to highlight the common "open circuit, 5 bands, one white" theme.  I've also added a new tag "fusible-resistor" with a tag-wiki entry, and have started going through similar questions adding this tag.

Is this a sensible approach?  Are there any other suggestions on what I should/shouldn't do?

Comment: Please explain what problem you are trying to address.

Comment: There are quite a lot of historic questions related to identification of burnt resistors with 5 bands, which don't fit the normal colour coding.  Answers to a couple of the questions have correctly identified the component as a fusible resistor, and one even includes a list of typical colour schemes. However, a fair number don't twig the component is a fusible resistor. I have answered many of the unanswered questions, created a "fusible-resistor" tag, and tagged all those which are relevant.  I've also added a tag wiki, and a link to the colour code answer.  Sensible?

Comment: I have also editted a number of the titles to highlight "5 bands" "burnt" "white/black/green last band". Key goal is to help people searching for identify of the failed component.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. There's the observational issue (read: it doesn't happen often, so one *perceives* that there might be a reason why not; but that's just correlation, or coincidence, not an actual reason) that such answers would get repeated. I suppose that might be a good meta question itself: whether repeating answers (across similar questions) is frowned upon in any way, or indeed preferable. Given that so many questions repeat over time, it seems fair that answers could too.